# How to go back to previous switch?

Tags: java

So I wanted my switch to be if the user chooses the switch(b) No it will go back to switch(a) the previous switch. How can I do it? I'm quite new to Java.

```
    switch(a){
        case 1:
            System.out.println("Here are the available rooms.");
            System.out.println("[1] Room No. 1");
            System.out.println("[2] Room No. 2");
            System.out.println("[3] Room No. 3");
            System.out.println("[4] Room No. 4");
            System.out.println("[5] Room No. 5\n");
            System.out.print("\nWhich room would you like? [1-5]:");
            b= sc.nextInt();

            switch(b){
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Room No. 1 costs $200 per stay.");
                    System.out.println("[1] Yes");
                    System.out.println("[2] No");
                    System.out.print("Do you wish to proceed? :");
                    c=sc.nextInt();
                    break;
            }

        break;
    }
```

Comment: `switch` is not a loop, it's not expected to go back to the outer `switch`.

Comment: *"How can I do it?"* You need a **loop** for that.

Comment: This is a broad topic that can't really be properly addressed within a StackOverflow answer. You should think about your control flow in a fundamentally different way. Consider for example https://www.gamedev.net/articles/programming/general-and-gameplay-programming/state-machines-in-games-r2982/

Comment: I would get rid of the state variables `a` and `b` and the switch statement, and rewrite the whole thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to use a labelled loop:

```
theLabel: while (true) { // whatever condition, whatever kind of loop:
  switch (a) {
      case 1:
        // ...
        switch (b) {
          case 1:
            // ...
            continue theLabel;
        }
  }
}
```

This will jump back to the start of the outer loop, thus it would execute the switch on a again.

But really, this is not a good way to structure it. There is nearly always a better way than using labelled loops, for example extracting some of the nested logic to a method.

In this case, I'd question the use of a switch for "room 1-room 5". Unless there is specific logic for each of the rooms, just use (for example) an array or list or map to store the prices for each of the rooms.

Answer (score -1):

If your question is about going from moving switch b to switch a. Then you can use the **recursion** for this purpose.

I don't know about return types. So the prototype is

Write the switch(a) in a method. Let's name this method as method1.

write switch(b) in a method. Let's name this method as method2.

```
method1(Object a)
{
   switch(a):
         case 1:
                 //Your code here
                 if(condition1)
                {
                     method2(a);
                }
}

method2(Object b )
{
     switch(b):
              if(condition2)
              {
                 method1(b)
              }

}
```